# how to sentence simplification for given string using python

Tags: python-3.x

> Example: I am going to Chennai i will go to office.
>
> Ans : Sent 1 : I am going to Chennai.

```
    Sent 2 : I will go to office.
```

Comment: Look at [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.split#str.split) if there is a simple rule for splitting the sentences. Or for more complex rules you will need to look at the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html?highlight=re#module-re)  module. But just as a matter of English the above is only one sentence, with 2 clauses (a comma `,` does not end a sentence)

Comment: i said simply with , that is not a main keyword. i will tell you one more example: i am intelligent but i am shy, Ans: SENT1: I am intelligent SENT2: I am shy

Comment: For this you need to build a more complex parser. You are looking at english clauses in a sentence and there are a number of conjunction words (and, but, so, etc.) or punctuation that introduce clauses. But this is a non-trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

For the given example, it might work with str.split:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm
If you have something more complicated to split, try regular expressions:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: This really isn't an answer but more a comment, and a repeat of an existing comment.

Comment: yup.. this is not a answer for above question. please check carefully.

Comment: I am going to Chennai i will go to office. for this

Answer (score 0):

```
my_sent = "I am going to Chennai, then i will go to office."
sent1 , sent2 = my_sent.split(", than")
```

The method **split** splits the string by given character or string value, and returns list of elements that were separated by given character.
Now we can put that values into variables. In that example *sent1* and *sent2*.

Comment: I am going to Chennai i will go to office. for this?

Comment: `print (sent1)` -> I am going to Chennai `print(sent2)` ->  i will go to office.